# PHP Header not Working (No Errors!)

Tags: php

so I had my website for a while now and now the host made some changes, so I had to change all my file names from *.html to *.php. Obviously made the necessary changes, yet now the .php extension seems to have done a couple of additional things.

`Header("Location: page.php");` doesn't work anymore, as seen in this example:

```
if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

The chunk of code above does what it's supposed to do, but instead of re-directing to `index.php` page, it adds a `?logoff` in page name, and I have to manually head to another page to fix this. Could you explain me why, and how I can solve this ?

What is strange is that `Header` works perfectly fine in other files. This is really frustrating.

Comment: is there any more code before this snippet?

Comment: I would be more concerned with why `logoff` is suddenly appearing in your GET params and fixing it rather than working around it.

Comment: have you output anything to the screen? Even a single space will send the headers and prevent this from working

Comment: Do your other "Location:" headers use relative locations? HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI: see [PHP Manual: header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-notes) and [RFC 2616 14.30](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)

Comment: Well the ?logoff is presumably in your link, since you're checking for `$_GET["logoff"]` in your code. The question is why it's not redirecting. Possibly there is whitespace or some other output before this code, and your errors are being suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

for the first...  $_SESSION is a global var... why you declare it? And for use $_SESSION, on top of the page you must write [session_start()](https://www.php.net/session_start) and, for header , i'll suggest you to use: [ob_start](https://www.php.net/ob_start)

Comment: if the header doesn't work, use the ob_start (the link is up),

Comment: an example of the use of the ob_start is: 
`ob_start(); `
And after in your code:
`if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    session_destroy();
    ob_end_clean ; 
    die(header("Location: index.php"));
}`
ob_start : goes on top of the page with session_start
ob_end_clean : http://it2.php.net/ob_end_clean and it goes before the header...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

on the top of the file to debug the PHP Errors

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out the issue, none of the solutions worked so I will just use the client-sided alternative:
`printf("<script>window.location = 'link';</script>");`